# How to determine if IP address in whitelist with IPy?

Tags: python, networking

In Python I am using the [IPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/) module to work with a set of IP addresses such as:
- Google's DNS (8.8.8.8)
- Some other Google IPs such as 209.85.128.0/17
etc.

```
myWhiteList = Set(IP('8.8.8.8'), IP('209.85.128.0/17'))
```

Currently, I take the IP address and subnet mask and create a huge list with all the IPs in the form:

```
for i in IP('209.85.128.0/17'):
    myList.add(i)
```

And then check whether my given IP is in this master list.  Is there a more efficient way of checking IPs in a list with IPy instead of expanding the IPs like I do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like [this](http://www.topdog.za.net/2012/05/06/python-modules-you-should-know%3a-ipy/):

```
from IPy import IP
if '192.168.0.1' in IP('192.168.0.0/30'):
    print "My IP is in the whitelist! Yay!"
```

Or in your case when you have several networks in a list:

```
for white_net in myWhiteList:
    if my_ip in white_net:
        print "My IP is in the whitelist! Yay!"
        break
```

Or, you can combine it in a single line:

```
my_ip = '209.85.128.1'
is_in_whitelist = any([my_ip in white_net for white_net in myWhiteList])
```

Comment: Yes, but I have more than one IP range.

Comment: That was just an example. You can iterate over the ranges in your set. I have updated the answer with another example.